# What is MASQUERADE made for?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, redirection

A simple redirection is used on my server, with iptables rules :

> $ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 13.37.42.1:80
>
> $ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

I dont understand the utility of the second line (masquerade).
Why/WhatFor is it useful in this example ?

EDIT :
Why - not theorically, but IRL - would you use it in such an example ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there’s no interface specification on the `MASQUERADE` rule?

Comment: I dont understand them. I d like to get a pragmatic feedback from real users of it. Generally, why do u use  it ? ... Specs, docs, has not help me to understand anything but theory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MASQUERADE` does what the name suggests: It hides everything “behind” the host. You’d do that to supply Internet to multiple hosts when you only have one uplink IP address. This tech is used on most consumer-grade Internet access routers, dubbed “NAT”.

When host A contacts server S via `MASQUERADE`ing router R, the server won’t be able to see the connection originates from host A. Instead, to the server it looks like it’s communicating with router R. Router R however knows this connection was originally from host A and will forward messages accordingly. Host A knows it connected to server S and that server S sent the response.

In IPTables, you’d usually use this only on the Internet-facing interface. Something like that:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Meaning that every IP packet that was routed and leaves through `eth0` will get the treatment.

When used in your example, it looks to `13.37.42.1` (host S) as if your machine (henceforth host Y) initiated the connection. That means the response will reach host Y which forwards it to the real destination (host A). To host A, it will look as if the message came from host Y. It cannot see or know that host S actually sent it, because `MASQUERADE` works both ways here.

If you do not use this rule, host S will see a message that originated from host A. It will thus send the response directly to host A. Host A, however, does not know host S. It connected to host Y and expects a response from there. As such, the response from host S is treated as unsolicited traffic and discarded. The connection will time out.

Comment: Does `MASQUERADE` automatically use the conntrack module to track response packets? I see lots of tutorials not mentioningg the usage of conntrack after adding the `MASQUERADE` target, but it seems the conntrack would have to be involved to deal with inverse-mapping the response packets.

Furthermore, are new TCP connection packets from server S considered `RELATED` packets to the initial connection or are they `NEW` packets instead and therefore would be blocked.

Comment: `conntrack` is used in the `FORWARD` chain to open the firewall for these connections. Otherwise the `FORWARD` chain's default behavior is `DROP`, the packet just don't get though the router. So all the work with `SNAT`, `DNAT` or `MASQUERADE` was useless.