# How does iptables nat work with ports?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, iptables

This is a theoretical question.

So, to enable NAT on "router" machine, we enable [masquerading](https://superuser.com/a/935988/291986) and all connections within "private" network are seen to external services (e.g. websites) as if that "router" initiated them.

But what about ports? Let's say I have 2 clients in private network: A and B. Imagine they both initiate connection to a service (maybe for different ones) using port 5000. How will "router" handle this? Does `iptables` have an internal "hashmap" or something like that which has (pseudocode):

• Proxy all requests from A:5000 via port 9000
• Proxy all requests from B:5000 via port 9001

And whenever A transfers something on port 5000, "router" forward this connection through its port 9000 and when external webserver replies, "router" receives the reply on port 9000 and forwards to `A`'s port 5000. Same goes for B, but with port 9001 on "router".

Is it correct?

Update: I'm currently testing with WireShark and Curl. Using `--local-port 5000` on both clients and connecting to the same website simultaneously with speed throttling. And Wireshark shows that both connections are using the same port. But how?

Comment: Feels like I've [already answered](https://superuser.com/a/1253026/1686) this one...

Comment: Specifically, see the 2nd section "Conflicts between computers", it has a port collision example nearly identical to yours.